# Parsing JSON Response in Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, grafana-templating

I have a Kubernetes environment and using Grafana to visualise metrics streamed from Prometheus.
I have application counters which are not fed to Prometheus. However I am able to view them as a JSON object by using a curl command.

http://10.0.0.1:8081/api/events/

Response has the following format:

```
{
{
  "ID":   "001",
  "source": "pageloads",
  "summary":  "high failure counts",
  "severity": "major"
},
{
  "ID":   "003",
  "source": "profile_counts",
  "summary":  "profile count doesn't match number of groups",
  "severity": "minor"
},
{
  "ID":   "002",
  "source": "number of subscribers",
  "summary":  "profiles higher than subscribers",
  "severity": "critical"
}
}
```

Is there a plugin to query this data (http://10.0.0.1:8081/api/events/) in Grafana?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to visualize this using the [AJAX Panel plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/ryantxu-ajax-panel).